# Merging an 'echo' and 'include' string to print an array

Tags: php

How can I separate the below php into an 'include' whilst calling the array? My reasoning is that that will be more resourceful (i.e. less demand on the server).

Currently all the below is a single 'include' string - am I correct in that approach or can you merge both an echo and include function at the same time?

Here's the code that I am currently pulling from a single php-include file:

```
<?php echo $message[0] ?>

<?php
$message1 = '<a href=""><img src="1.png"></a>';
$message2 = '<a href=""><img src="2.png"></a>';
$message3 = '<a href=""><img src="3.png"></a>';
$message4 = '<a href=""><img src="4.png"></a>';
$message = array($message1, $message2, $message3, $message4);
shuffle($message);
?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? I'm not sure that calling an `include` during an `echo` will be more resourceful.

Comment: Maybe you should use OOP. You can easily create a class and just echo the returned value of that. :)

Comment: I havent tried because I am still trying to figure out if I can concatenate two functions like that? Sorry if my terminology is all off - I am just learning...

Comment: Where's your `include` statement? You can return a value from a file that you `include` or `require` which you can directly output through `echo`, `print`, etc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but anyway: `echo $message[0]` is before you create the `$message` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull all the code togheter:

```
<?php
$message1 = '<a href=""><img src="1.png"></a>';
$message2 = '<a href=""><img src="2.png"></a>';
$message3 = '<a href=""><img src="3.png"></a>';
$message4 = '<a href=""><img src="4.png"></a>';
$message = array($message1, $message2, $message3, $message4);
shuffle($message);
echo $message[0];
?>
```

and make it in one file:

```
random_echo.php
```

and then just call

```
<?php
 include "random_echo.php";
?>
```

that will make the same effect.
To be less resourcefull maybe you can try this:

```
<?php
$message = array(
   '<a href=""><img src="1.png"></a>',
   '<a href=""><img src="2.png"></a>',
   '<a href=""><img src="3.png"></a>',
   '<a href=""><img src="4.png"></a>'
);
shuffle($message);
echo $message[0];
?>
```

or even better if it apply:

```
<?php
$message = array(
   '1.png',
   '2.png',
   '3.png',
   '4.png'
);
shuffle($message);
echo '<a href=""><img src="'.$message[0].'"></a>';
?>
```

I mean always inside tour random_echo.php that you will later include.

The difference is not visible anyway, not on a small array or a small number of calls.
This should not stop you from write the better code you can think of, of course.